# Visual C++, Organize .h and .cpp Files in Folders

Tags: c++, filter, directory

I've never had a C++ project that has required organizing stuff in folders before, because I mostly use C# for everything, but now I have this kind of project. What I have done is right click on "Header Files" in the solution explorer, and looked for "Add Folder", but there is no such thing. However, there is something called a "Filter", and it appears to work like a folder, but I don't know if this is how C++ uses folders, or what. Is this the case, using filters as folders, or is there a way to make folders?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is a visual studio and not a C++ thing. Usually, it is recommended to split into folders each library or program.

Answer (score 5):

You can use filters if you like. These place files into pseudo-folders based on their file extensions. By default, you get header files in "Header Files", source files in "Source Files", etc., but these are customizable, as you've found out.

However, if you prefer the Solution Explorer to reflect the file system, then that is an option as well. Just click the "Show All Files" button at the top of the Solution Explorer to toggle it on. The filters will no longer be active (although they'll still be saved with your project settings so that you can toggle them back on at any time), and you will see the folders exactly as they are in the file system. You can drag-and-drop files between folders, create new folders, and everything, just as you normally would.

[image] <sub>(overcompressed JPG image stolen from [Ben Williams' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benwilli/archive/2015/05/21/vs-tip-8-adding-existing-files-with-show-all-files.aspx))</sub>

I prefer to keep the filters disabled and see the file system in the Solution Explorer. But I'm a control freak—I like files to be exactly where I put them.

The obvious drawback of this, of course, is that you'll see *all* files in your solution's directory on disk, even those that have not been added to your project/solution. Those that have not been included will appear grayed out or with a dotted outline, and can be easily included by right-clicking and selecting "Include In Project."

Answer (score 0):

You can add projects to Visual Studio solution. Each project would be in separate folder. They also can be stored hierarchically.